# How do I save a level layout in a variable

Tags: python, pygame

Currently, My next project is going to be a platformer and when I look around stackoverflow for research on several mechanics, I see many people doing the same thing: They save a layout with some variable, then go and unload it somewhere and it just renders in the game. I was interested, so I looked further and I found nothing on how to load/unload states like that, or maybe I'm just not wording my search correctly.

Either way, How do I do this?

ex: I would save a level layout as either an array or a single multi-line string and then somehow generate a single tile sprite for each letter, like T.

```
import pygame

# Storage method A
level = '''
X X X X X
X X X X X
T T X X X
X X X T T
T T T T T
'''

# Storage Method B

level2 = [ 
    'XXXXX',
    'XXXXX',
    'TTXXX',
    'XXXTT',
    'TTTTT'
]

# X is blank space, T is tiles

# Then what? Thats what I need to know.
# If someone already answered this and I'm just not using the right keywords let me know.
```

Comment: using ``` is a block commenting method. You're not storing anything in method A (and it will return an error). In method B you are saving them as a list, which is a basic container in python. Is this not doing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the enumerated rows and characters in the layout, create the tile instances and add them to a sprite group.

In the example I just give the tiles different colors depending on the character in the layout (X=blue, T=green) before I add them to the group, but you could also create completely different `Tile` types or subclasses if the character is a 'T' or an 'X'.

```
import pygame


class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)


def create_tile_group(layout):
    """Turn the layout into a sprite group with Tile instances."""
    group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for y, row in enumerate(layout):
        for x, tile in enumerate(row):
            if tile == 'T':
                color = (50, 150, 50)
            else:
                color = (0, 0, 200)
            group.add(Tile((x*tile_size, y*tile_size), color))
    return group


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

layout1 = [
    'XXXXX',
    'XTXXX',
    'XXXXT',
    'XXXXX',
    'TTTTT',
    ]

tile_size = 50
tile_group = create_tile_group(layout1)

loop = True
while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False

    tile_group.update()

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    tile_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

If you get performance problems because you blit too many small surfaces, you could blit them onto a big background surface before the while loop starts and then just blit the background once each frame.

Comment: Alright, Ill try this code and get back to you, thanks @skrx

Comment: It worked, thanks @skrx. Now im going to mess around with what I can do with it

Answer (score 2):

You will need to calculate the pixel-positions for each tile. To draw any tile, you need to know

1. the size of the canvas
2. the size of your grid
3. the position of the tile in your grid

1: Finding the size of your canvas should be trivial.

2: For the second storage method you can do

```
height = len(level2)
width = len(level2[0]) #Assuming all rows are of equal length and there's at least one row
```

3: We're going to iterate through the rows and characters which will keep track of our position in the grid on the side.

```
def draw_tiles(canvas_width, canvas_height, width, height, level2):
  for row in range(height):
    for column in range(width):
      if list(level2[row])[column] == 'T':
        pixel_x = int(canvas_width/width)*column
        pixel_y = int(canvas_height/height)*row
        draw_tile(pixel_x, pixel_y)
```

Now all you need to do is define the draw_tile(x, y) function to draw a tile on the canvas with its top-left corner being on the pixel co-ordinates (x, y). I'm sure pygame has something for that.

Make sure you set the grid width/height so that canvas_width/width and canvas_height/height are both integers. Otherwise your tiles will be slightly offset due to rounding.

Comment: alright, Ill try this method and ill get back to you, thanks!

Comment: Within the `pixel_x = canvas_width - int(canvas_width/column)` part of the function it divides by zero, what do I do? @user181934

Comment: You've found a bug in my code. I'll edit my answer with the fix.

Comment: Well now its spitting out dividing by zero errors` @user181934

Comment: The only denominators in my code snippet are width and height. They should both be greater than zero. If they're not the culprits, the error is coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic here: "it just renders in the game" is not accurate.  There's more software behind the rendering call, a module that defines the tile sprites, scans the level character by character, and places the sprites accordingly.  The developer (e.g. you) decides on the level representation, sprite form, sprite placement, etc.

You have several bits of code to write.  The good news is that *you* decide the format; you just have to stay consistent when you write those modules.